# When will new value for CPUAffinity= in systemd come into effect?

Tags: systemd, affinity

If I change `CPUAffinity=` or `CPUQuota=` in a systemd unit configuration file such as `postgresql@.service`, when will the new settings come into effect? In particular, will I have to restart the service in order to see the service's processes executing on the intended CPUs and will they run there under guarantee?

Answer (score 2):

According to the testing that I have just done (why, oh why, does the [documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-system.conf.html) not clarify this!), **changing the CPUAffinity requires a reboot**.

I tried changing the value and then

1. restarting processes - no effect
2. `systemctl daemon-reload` - no effect
3. `systemctl daemon-reexec` - no effect
4. reboot

Only the reboot effected the change to CPUAffinity.

Tested on CentOS 7.

Also, for those finding the documentation lacking, the CPU numbering goes from zero, you can specify ranges (such as `1-3` and multiples may be given either space or comma-delimnited).

Comment: This is incorrect, see my answer. If you restarted the service after step 2 the affinity would be applied.

Comment: I found this to be the case too when testing with a random process (I was using a python interpreter + psutil to self-fech its own affinity). Only after a reboot I could see the new CpuAffinity having an effect.

Comment: I have a question. Is it possible to set CPUAffinity=0 for a specific process (lets say httpd.service) in its systemd service unit file?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to reload the configuration (`systemctl daemon-reload`) then restart the service.

See for example [here](https://www.golinuxhub.com/2018/01/how-to-assign-service-to-specific-core.html). There's no need to reboot the system like starfry suggests.

Answer (score 0):

1. Edit your service:

```
systemctl edit service.service
```

2. Add your CPUAffinity:

```
[service]
CPUAffinity=0
```

3. Reload systemd:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

4. Restart your service

```
systemctl restart service.service
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. Yes, this procedure will make the change effective, but I was interested in the "earliest" mechanism that does so in this specific context.